# How to install Tor on Raspbian such that I get an icon?

Tags: raspbian

I want to install Tor on a Raspberry Pi 2 such that I get an icon and it starts after I click the said icon.

I am using Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [Alexy's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44974/how-to-install-tor-on-raspbian-such-that-i-get-an-icon#answer-44975)... An alternative method to right clicking to create the shortcut, which unfortunately, does not seem to work for me on Raspbian Wheezy, is as follows.

Create a *blank file*, by right clicking and selecting *Create New->Empty File* in the `/home/pi/Desktop/` directory, and call it `Tor.desktop` e.g.

```
/home/pi/Desktop/Tor.desktop
```

Then edit it and paste in the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Tor
Comment=My shortcut to Tor
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/openbox.xpm
Exec=/usr/tor/bin/tor -f /etc/torrc
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

Save it, and you *should* now have a Tor shortcut on your desktop.

Comment: Why not use `Categories=Network;`? Tor is clearly network-related.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - good point, I had overlooked that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just install Tor from source or expert bundle - after that **just** make a shortcut by right-clicking and selecting it.

I do recommend you to put an *explicit* pointer to `torrc` in the command line in the shortcut, so that there will be no surprises, like this:

```
/usr/tor/bin/tor -f /etc/torrc
```

Comment: Isn't the Tor expert bundle only for Windows? I don't see one for Raspian, on the [Tor pages](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en), as this (rather old) [SE Tor post](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/242/how-to-run-tor-on-raspbian-on-the-raspberry-pi) explains. Aren't Pi users just restricted to what comes with Raspbian? Maybe I am missing something..? Do you have any links?

Comment: @Greenonline they're not restricted, actually. Expert pack for linux can be obtained via Tor's deb repository. IMHO - just IMHO - use source code build. I'm using it on Raspbian and on Armbian - no problems detected, it's a very easy task to do so.